# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, top-7, faq-for-site

Since this is one of the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)...

**What should go in our FAQ?**

Most of the FAQ is boilerplate, but we need to determine the on-topic and off-topic subjects that go into that particular section of the official FAQ.  Those should be derived from the original site definition and the current set of questions.

**Example template:**

Following the example set out in the linked page, the section being discussed here might look like this:

> {Site Name} is for professional and amateur video game developers, designers, artists; and anyone else who is involved in the games development industry.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - {On-topic subject}
> - {On-topic subject}
> - ...
>
> and it is **not about:**
>
> - {Off-topic subject}
> - {Off-topic subject}
> - {Off-topic subject}
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

**Answer format:**

Please post **one subject** and specify whether or not it is an on-topic or off-topic.  Note that your answer should **not** be in the form of a specific example question; it should refer to an **entire subject group**.  Example of such a response:

> **{On-topic}**
>
> **Tools used by Game Developers**
>
> <sup>(Optional  comments)</sup>

Please **vote up** answers if you **agree** with the proposed on-topic/off-topic status.  **Vote down** answers where you **disagree.**

Comment: CAPTCHA: Moscow aerosols

Comment: And yes, I mostly stole this from cooking.stackexchange

Answer (score 7):

**{Off-topic}**

### Hints, tips, strategies or cheat codes for games

Comment: A link to http://gaming.stackexchange.com would be nice after this sentence ;)

Answer (score 4):

**{On-topic}**

**Issues relating to game design, such as gameplay, ideas, mechanics, etc**

<sup>([Taken from the bullet list in my answer here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14))</sup>

Answer (score 4):

**{On-topic}**

**Programming questions *unique* to video game development, or where a professional game developer would give a *substantially different* answer than other programmers (general programming questions should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com))**

<sup>([Taken from the bullet list in my answer here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14))</sup>

<sup>(The language here could probably be tightened up a bit... and the statement about general programming questions could probably be moved to its own "Off-topic" post... feel free to edit)</sup>

Comment: Other than dropping the "video" I think it's about as concise as possible. But I'm not an English major or anything.

Answer (score 4):

**{On-topic}**

**Development practices relating game development including testing, tools, team collaboration, etc**

<sup>([Taken from the bullet list in my answer here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14))</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**{On-topic}**

### Programming, designing, producing, marketing, or creating art or music/sound for games

(probably to be split into several bullet points)

(unsure about "marketing", and are there any areas I forgot?)

Comment: I think we should break this up a bit to make each point more vote-able.

Answer (score 2):

**{On-topic}**

**The creation, storage, editing and usage of game assets such as images, video, sound and music**

<sup>([Taken from the bullet list in my answer here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14))</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**{On-topic}**

**The release of a finished video game, such as questions on hosting, publishing, marketing and monetization**

<sup>([Taken from the bullet list in my answer here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14))</sup>

Comment: But deliberate advertisement with no/half-hearted/dummy/frivolous question is a no-no. Right?

Answer (score 2):

**{On-topic}**

**Questions relevant to developers about the video game industry, covering topics like careers, trends and technologies**

<sup>([Taken from the bullet list in my answer here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow/14#14))</sup>