# Is it OK to ask questions towards developing non-game software?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am sure this has been asked somewhere here in some form but I couldn't find it so sorry if mine is a duplicate.

For part of the piece of software I need to construct some very game-like mechanisms (for example, a navigable 3D surface with overlays, a HUD, etc.) even though the software is not a game at all. Are these questions appropriate for this website?

Answer (score 5):

If it's programming related, see this question: [Programming Questions: Here or "Belongs on Stackoverflow"?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow)  Or more specifically, if you think that it's something a game programmer would be able to answer more correctly than a non-game programmer, it's probably welcome.  If it's "how do I get so and so to talk to a database", it probably isn't.